# css align multiple line contenteditable content on right side

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a basic multi-line input form with html css etc... For the inputs I'm using a contenteditable="true" span instead of the regular , and also I don't want to use tables.

That being said, I'm trying to line of the text "labels" and the input boxes, like this picture:
[image]

everythings working fine more or less, except when the contenteditable reaches multiple lines. I need the multi-line thing to line up with the labels and not reset to the beginning of the line. Here's the code so far:

```css
   input, .new_input {
      
        border:0;
        outline:0;
        background:transparent;
        border-bottom:1px solid black;
       
    }

   
    .titlething {
        display:inline-block;
       text-align:right;
       width:80px;
     margin-left:-20px;
        
    }
     #word_edit {
        position:absolute;
        max-width:300px;
        border:1px #0F23D5 solid;
        padding:4px;
        background:#A1C9E4;
        border-radius:15px;
        padding:15px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="word_edit">

<label>
<span class="titlething">Meaning</span>
<span class="new_input" data-placeholder="Meaning:"  data-name="meaning" contenteditable="true">some default text</span></br>
</label>
<label>
<span class="titlething">Phonetic</span>
<span class="new_input" data-placeholder="Phonetic:"  contenteditable="true" data-name="phonetic">hi</span></br>
</label>
<label>
<span class="titlething">Other</span>
<span class="new_input" data-placeholder="Other:"  contenteditable="true" data-name="other">test</span></br>
</label>
<button data-name="done">Done!</button>
</div>
```

As you can see, everything works more-or-less until you get to the next line, but I need the new line to start at the same place as the first line.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the snippet below, I added 2 lines:

`display: inline-block;` to `.new_input`
and
`vertical-align: top;` to `.titlething`

```css
input,
.new_input {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background: transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

.titlething {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  width: 80px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#word_edit {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 300px;
  border: 1px #0F23D5 solid;
  padding: 4px;
  background: #A1C9E4;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="word_edit">

  <label>
<span class="titlething">Meaning</span>
<span class="new_input" data-placeholder="Meaning:"  data-name="meaning" contenteditable="true">some default text</span></br>
</label>
  <label>
<span class="titlething">Phonetic</span>
<span class="new_input" data-placeholder="Phonetic:"  contenteditable="true" data-name="phonetic">hi</span></br>
</label>
  <label>
<span class="titlething">Other</span>
<span class="new_input" data-placeholder="Other:"  contenteditable="true" data-name="other">test</span></br>
</label>
  <button data-name="done">Done!</button>
</div>
```